# How can I upgrade my house in skyrim whiterun after I have already furnished it?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have already furnished my house in Whiterun but want to make it better. Is there an option and if so how do I upgrade my house?

Comment: You only have the base game, and not the Hearthfire DLC?

Comment: The only alterations you can make once you have completely furnished it (I believe) is exchanging your alchemy room for a bedroom for your child/children (I'm unsure on how many beds it is - I've never done this).

Answer (score 3):

Nope, there is nothing you can do to improve your house any further. As soon as you bought every available option, it's done.

The only way to upgrade your house any further is by using mods. There are tons of breezehome (or any player home really) mods on the nexus you can use. However, most of them will change the interior drastically.